# app post is not working i am not getting the output

Tags: node.js, express

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var port = 3000;
const fs = require('fs');

// we are connecting to the  mangodb using mangoose
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

// Now we are using bodyParser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/YourDB", { useNewUrlParser: true })

// now we are creating the schema to the database
var nameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 firstName: String,
 lastNameName: String
});

// Now we have to create a model

var User = mongoose.model("User", nameSchema);



app.use("/", (req,  res) => {
 res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");

});
// Now we are posting the data



app.post("/addname", (req, res) => {
  console.log("nnnnnn")
  console.log(req.body.firstName)
 var myData = new User(req.body);
 myData.save()
 console.log(myData);
 fs.writeFile(__dirname +"/data.json",myData,  function(err){
   if(err) {
     return console.log(err);
   }
   console.log("The file is saved ");
 })
 console.log(myData)

})

// Now we are getting the data


app.listen(port, () => {
 console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
});
```

1)I am using express  app.post to post the data into database  and  store the data into the write file  to check

2) app.post is not working it tried console.log to check but  it  is not going inside the function

3) I am not getting output as well as any error plese help me

Comment: can you provide the request which you are making?

Answer (score 0):

there is no error handling and response handling in this code.
it will be readable if we write `post` method with `async/await` :

```
app.post("/addname", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("nnnnnn")
  console.log(req.body.firstName)
 var myData = new User(req.body);
 await myData.save()
 console.log(myData);
 fs.writeFileSync(__dirname +"/data.json", myData)
 console.log(myData)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for  response 
hi i tried but i am getting the same issue

Comment: @VenkateshMuthyla also check your mongoose schema. try this one: `var myData = new User({... req.body })`.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Intro to Node and MongoDB</title>
 </head>

 <body>
 <h1>Into to Node and MongoDB</h1>
 <form method="post" action="/addname">
 <label>Enter Your Name</label><br>
 <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter first name..." required>
 <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Enter last name..." required>
 <input type="submit" value="Add Name">
 </form>
 </body>
</html>

my html code

Comment: can you please edit my code with html i tried i am getting soome isssue  as i am new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

That's because every request is going to this `app.use` code block. `app.use("/", (req,  res) => { ... });`

Just Put it below the `app.post("/addname", (req, res) => { ... });`

`app.use` is used to mount [middlewares](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) into the request-response chain. So, every request that comes matches the `/`(which is essentially every request) goes inside that middleware. So, use your routes first then use the middleware at the end.

**EDIT:**
Let me give you a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which I tested locally:

```
const express = require('express');
const fakeData = function(){
    return {
        s: "fakeData"
    }
}
const app = express();
const port = 8181
const path = require('path')
app.get("/a", (req,  res) => {
    return res.json({d:'yay'});
   
   });
app.use('/',(req,res)=>{
    return res.json(fakeData());
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on PORT ${port}`);
});
```

Because every request goes through a mounted middleware, so when you `GET`/`POST`/ANYTHING to **`localhost:8181/<abosulutely_any_path>`** it will go through the `app.use` because it treats that function as middleware and will return `{ s: "fakeData" }`.

But when you make a `GET` call **`http://localhost:8181/a`** it will go to the `app.get` route **BECAUSE WE DECLARED IT FIRST** and return `{ d : "yay" }`

Comment: hi 

i tried it i also taught of removing completely  app.use now i am getting error (because we don't want to  use any middleware now i am getting error )

Comment: what error are you getting? and did you put the App.use below the App.post? because i tried an example code and it worked.

Comment: it solved but app.use is a just middleware  i removed the app.use  and  kept the res.sendFile inside my router then my page stopped loading any suggestion why ?

Comment: Edited the answer, please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

you will add next() to app.use

```
var User = mongoose.model("User", nameSchema);



app.use("/", (req,  res,next) => {
 res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
next()
});
// Now we are posting the data



app.post("/addname", (req, res) => {
  console.log("nnnnnn")
  console.log(req.body.firstName)
 var myData = new User(req.body);
 myData.save()
 console.log(myData);
 fs.writeFile(__dirname +"/data.json",myData,  function(err){
   if(err) {
     return console.log(err);
   }
   console.log("The file is saved ");
 })
 console.log(myData)

})

// Now we are getting the data


app.listen(port, () => {
 console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The POST request in nodejs usually don't work if there is syntactical error in HTML file.As per the comment the modified HTML is mentioned in the post and is tested and working fine

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Intro to Node and MongoDB</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Intro to Node and MongoDB</h1>
<form action="/addname" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="FirstName">
    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="LastNumber">
    <button type="submit">Add Value</button>
    
</form>
</body>

</html>
```